# Partial Update of a webpage ASP.NET Core radiobuttons

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, razor

Web Page Image of the Interface
[image]
The image above shows what the interface should look like. The red highlight needs to be dynamic.
Depending on the API selection (which is dynamic depending on a config file).

This is the example config I am using.

```
"APIS": [
{
  "APIID": 0,
  "APIName": "First",
  "Enabled": true,
  "APIPort": 1234,
  "Endpoints": [
    {
      "ID": 1,
      "Enabled": true,
      "FriendlyName": "First Second Option",
      "Mapping": "[MAPPING HIDDEN]"
    }
  ]
 }
]
```

When I select the other API radio button, it needs to update the Endpoint options (as shown on the image).
The endpoint options can vary in length (One API may have one, another may have 2).

I have been looking for a solution for a few days, and have been unable to find one.

I believe I need to use AJAX to complete this partial update.

Please could someone help with the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, it seems that you want to show the related Endpoints options based on the selected API, if that is the case, you could refer to the following code (I assume you have created a Asp.net Core Razor page application):

Based on the config json file, create the following class:

```
public class APIS
{
    public int APIID { get; set; }
    public string APIName { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    public int APIPort { get; set; }
    public List<Endpoints> Endpoints { get; set; }
}

public class Endpoints
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    public string FriendlyName { get; set; }
    public string Mapping { get; set; }
}
```

In the Index.cshtml.cs file:

```
    [BindProperty]
    public List<APIS> APIS { get; set; }
    public void OnGet()
    {
        APIS = apiservice.GetAllAPI(); //get all API and the related endpoints. 
    }
    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public string apiname { get; set; }
    public JsonResult OnGetGetEndPoints()
    {
        APIS = apiservice.GetAllAPI(); //get all API and the related endpoints.

        return new JsonResult(APIS.Where(c => c.APIName == apiname).Select(c => c.Endpoints).ToList());
    }
```

Code in the Index.cshtml page (the `endpoints` div is used to populate the endpoints.):

```
<div >
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="">
            <h2>Please select API</h2>
            @foreach (var item in Model.APIS)
            {
                <input type="radio" id="radio_@item.APIName" class="radio_api" data-apiname="@item.APIName" name="APIName" /> @item.APIName
            }
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="">
            <h2>Please select Endpoints</h2>
            <div id="endpoints">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript code:

```
    @section Scripts{ 
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () { 
                $(".radio_api").each(function (index, item) {
                    $(item).click(function () {
                        var apiname = $(this).attr("data-apiname");
                        //using getJson method:
                        $.getJSON(`?handler=GetEndPoints&apiname=${apiname}`, (data) => {
                            $("#endpoints").html(""); //clear the container.
                            $.each(data[0], function (key, value) {
                                $("#endpoints").append(`<input type="radio" name="endpoint"/>${value.friendlyName}`);
                            });
                        }); 
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    }
```

Besides, you could also create a API and use JQuery Ajax to call the API method and load the endpoints:

```
                  $.ajax({
                            url: "api/values?apiname=" + apiname,
                            type: 'Get', 
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "json", 
                            error: function (exception) {
                                console.log(exception);
                            },
                            success: function (result) { 
                                //console.log("Success");
                                $("#endpoints").html("");

                                $.each(result[0], function (key, value) {
                                    $("#endpoints").append(`<input type="radio" name="endpoint"/>${value.friendlyName}`);
                                });
                            }
                        });
```

The screenshot like this:

[image]

Reference: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/ajax/cascading-dropdowns